# how to remember permissions on linux(debian based distro)

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

when I prove to read the usb serial /dev/ttyACM0, my code gives me this error:
`SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'`
I fixed this, whit this command: `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0`

But, when I reboot the pc, It doesn't remember the permission.

Answer (score 1):

For permanent effect:

`man adduser` -> `adduser [options] user group`

i.e. `adduser $USER dialout`

The `dialout` group could just as well be `serialports` or similar as the effect includes that. $USER will have access to all those regardless of name.

Comment: But, It tells me that I am already part of the dialout group

Comment: Please check this: http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/permissions-serial.html fro more indepth info

Comment: Even more info: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=access+serial+port+on+Linux

Comment: I've already seen this page, but these commands are not remembered by the computer. So on every reboot there will always be the error.

Comment: Well that is odd. What kind of Linux installation do you have? Hint: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454259/reset-all-files-after-reboot or  https://www.howtogeek.com/166205/how-to-easily-reset-a-computer-back-to-a-clean-state-each-time-it-boots/